# Test data sources in Android unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, resources

I want to test parsing of data returned from server.

I thought I might create several test XML files and then feed them to the sax parser which uses my custom data handler (as in the application that I test).

But where should I put those test XMLs?

I tried with `[project_root]/res/xml`, but then I get the error:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000 type #0x1c is not valid
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1870)
at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:779)`

Does that mean that the xml is invalid, or that android couldn't find the XML file?
(I use the same XML that comes from the server - copied it from the firebug's net panel and pasted into the file).

Can I somehow read that XML as a text file, since `getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.test_response1)` returns `XmlResourceParser` instead of `String` (which I'd prefer)?

Answer (score 1):

Put you xmls in `MyAppTest/assets`, for example `MyAppTest/assets/my.xml`, and then read it using

```
InputStream myxml = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("my.xml");
```

then you can invoke the parser with this stream.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test_response1.xml at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)

Comment: I don't know what's going on.. When I call getContext().getAssets().list("/"), I get a list of several files and folders among which is "assets" folder. When I then list files in "/assets" folder, I get nothing - as if the folder is empty...

Comment: Depending on where is the xml file (in your app's assets or your test's assers) you need the right context to find it through getAssets().

Comment: @dtmilano: Maybe I am blind in the moment, but I don't find a way to get the app context in a unit test in the test project. can you tell me one please?

Comment: getInstrumentation().getContext() and getInstrumentation().getTargetContext() should give you the contexts you need.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the file in your current package (ie into a resource package) and use the class loader...

```
private InputStream getTestImage(String pathToFile) throws IOException
        {
            final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            assertNotNull(loader);
            final InputStream resourceAsStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(pathToFile);
            assertNotNull(resourceAsStream);
            return resourceAsStream;
        }
```

Comment: I think this won't work due to: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10076  essentially becuase teh dex tool will ignore any non class files unless it's run with extra parameters.

Comment: This works fine for me using ICS when reading files placed in the the "res/raw" folder inside the **test** project (not the app project being tested!)